# Timer's callback thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, events, timer, callback

I was thinking about how timers work, and there's something I don't fully understand.
A `Timer` uses an event that is called when the time elapses. This I assume is triggered by an OS event that controls the clock (or is controlled by the clock).
But I'm not sure what thread will catch that event..

Does a `Timer` object have a thread of its own ?
Or will the event be called in the thread which created the timer object ?

EDIT:

And is there a difference in that aspect between `System.Timers.Timer`  and `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on the `Timer`. If you use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, the tick event will be handled in the UI thread. In `System.Threading.Timer` and `System.Timers.Timer` it defaults to a thread pool thread. However, in the latter case you can specify a [`SynchronizingObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.synchronizingobject.aspx) which can be used to marshal the handler to an appropriate thread.

Comment: Just to add to boot: And in the former case can simply specify the `state` object to be your sync object. .NET 4 uses `Dispatcher` as opposed to `ISynchronizeInvoke` for `WPF`, this can be used in the very same way - but can't be used with `System.Timers.Timer` in the aforementioned manner.

Comment: If it uses a thread pool, will the next trigger be in another thread? or the same thread it was before? Again, does the timer has its own designated thread ?

Comment: @Yochai: I believe it may occur on a different thread each time (although it *could* end up reusing the same one of course). I don't believe a thread is "reserved" for a timer.